# How can i disable the toggle, preventing user to tap/click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ratchet-bootstrap

I've tried

```
$(".toggle-handle").addClass("disabled")
$(".toggle").addClass("disabled")
$(".toggle-handle").off();
$(".toggle").off();
```

without success. I have forms that is just informative once saved to I would like to have them not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable is a property of the element:

```
$(".toggle-handle").prop('disabled', true);
```

Demo:

```js
$(".toggle-handle").prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-handle">Button</button>
```

Or using vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector('.toggle-handle').disabled = true;
```

Demo:

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle-handle').disabled = true;
```

```html
<button class="toggle-handle">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution using `CSS property`.

```css
button {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click ME!!!</button>
```

If you want to remove the disabled property, then set CSS property to

```
pointer-events: auto;
```

Hope this will help you.